# How to call a method from another class that's been instantiated within the current class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, methods

my screen has a few views like such

```
__________________
|          _____  |
|          |    | | //viewX is a video screen
|          |    | | 
| viewX    | vY | | //viewY is a custom uiview i created.
|          |____| | //it contains a method which i would like to call that toggles
|_________________| //the hidden property of this view. and when it hides, a little
|                 | //button is replaced no the top right corner on top of viewX
| viewZ           | //the video layer
|                 |
|_________________| //viewZ is a view containing many square views - thumbnails.
```

my question is, i dont know how to register for touch events so that it recognises any touch event on no matter which view the user touches the screen.. atm im handling the touch events for each view inside it. so all works well...

however what im trying to do is that when the user taps anywhere else on the screen but on viewY, viewY should dissapear by calling that method in the viewY class.

this viewY class is instantiated and has no xib file attached to it. the uiview is created progammatically in the viewY class. this whole class for viewY behviour is instantiated in viewX - the video view.

my boss says add delegates.. although i have now clue how to do that... any help?

is there anyway i can just make it really simple and be able to say REMOVE VIEW no matter which class im calling from?

Also ive seen other people achieve this by using these funky arrows -> ... <- etc.. although im not sure if thats what i need or how to implement such a thing.

ah i think ive made my question quite complicated but i really mean it to be a simple one, and know it can be done in an easy way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would not calling

```
[viewY hideThisViewAndShowLittleButton];
```

do the right job? If you want to remove viewY then you can call:

```
[viewY removeFromSuperview];
```

In order to access `viewY` from `viewZ`, provided that `viewZ` has access to `viewX`, you could define a method in `viewX` that returns to you `viewY`. Something like (in your implementation file for `viewX`:

```
- (UIView*)viewY {
   return <viewX_knows_which_value_to_return>;
}
```

As to `viewX_knows_which_value_to_return`, provided that `viewY` is the only subview, you could do:

```
[self.view.subviews lastObject];
```

(NB: I am assuming here that actually viewX is a view controller, not a UIView).

Comment: Yes this works if you call it within the class
however calling from a different class such as from viewZ then it wont work....

Comment: @did you init the uiview in the ViewController?

Comment: yes. it is a uiview init'd in that class.. as its a dynamic uiview i created adding quite a few buttons on it etc all programmatic.
then a method to toggle the uiview on and off
however in a different class... i dont have a clue how to access that same method thats in the other class already init'd

Comment: please, see my edit... if you provide the interface declarations for your classes, I could be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good way. 
You can even do it this way with  hidden or adding alpha.

```
vY.hidden = YES;
```

To get it back

```
vY.hidden = NO;
```